# Build Python dictionary from Pandas columns using loop

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas data frame as such

```
**Breed     Animal**
Orange Tab  Cat
Tuxedo      Cat
Tabby       Cat
Husky       Dog
Golden      Dog
Labrador    Dog
Poodle      Dog
Koi         Fish
Fantail     Fish
GoldFish    Fish
```

and would like to create a dictionary as such

```
  mydict = {
  "Cat": ['Orange Tab', 'Tuxedo', 'Tabby'],
  "Dog": ['Husky','Golden','Labrador','Poodle'],
  "Fish": ['Koi','Fantail','GoldFish']
}
```

I have never dealt with dictionary with Pandas data frame so I have no idea where to start.
I imagine I have to use a nested for loop but have no idea how to loop through the Animal part in the data frame.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

you can use [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby):

```
df.groupby('Animal**')['**Breed'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

output:

```
{'Cat': ['Orange Tab', 'Tuxedo', 'Tabby'],
 'Dog': ['Husky', 'Golden', 'Labrador', 'Poodle'],
 'Fish': ['Koi', 'Fantail', 'GoldFish']}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with list and then convert to dictionary:

```
result = df.groupby('Animal')['Breed'].apply(list)
print(result.to_dict())
```

**Output**

```
{'Cat': ['Orange Tab', 'Tuxedo', 'Tabby'], 'Dog': ['Husky', 'Golden', 'Labrador', 'Poodle'], 'Fish': ['Koi', 'Fantail', 'GoldFish']}
```